# How to read hadoop sequential file?

Tags: java, dictionary, hadoop, sequential, hadoop-streaming

I have a sequential file which is the output of hadoop map-reduce job.
In this file data is written in key value pairs ,and value itself is a map.
I want to read the value as a MAP object so that i can process it further.

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Path path = new Path("D:\\OSP\\sample_data\\data\\part-00000");
    SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(FileSystem.get(config), path, config);
    WritableComparable key = (WritableComparable) reader.getKeyClass().newInstance();
    Writable value = (Writable) reader.getValueClass().newInstance();
    long position = reader.getPosition();

    while(reader.next(key,value))
    {
           System.out.println("Key is: "+textKey +" value is: "+val+"\n");
    }
```

output of program: Key is: [this is key] value is: {abc=839177, xyz=548498, lmn=2, pqr=1}

Here i am getting value as string ,but i want it as a object of map.

Comment: Where comes `val` from? And a Map is not `Writable`, what are you using for classes in your m/r job?

Comment: I just have the sequential file and not aware of what they are doing in map reduce job.And i am provided with following information."Each such file needs to be opened as a sequence file. A decompression
codec needs to be used - the sequence file class seems to be able to
tell you what compression codec to use, and then I think each key and
each value is encoded using TypedBytes."

Comment: Then you have to get the classes of the key and values, otherwise you won't deserialize them properly.

Comment: The value class is "TypedBytesWritable" how could i get the Map object out of this?

Comment: @samarth  how to read compressed (gz / bz2 / snappy) sequence file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the API documentation for [SequenceFile#next(Writable, Writable)](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.Reader.html#next%28org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable,%20org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable%29)

```
while(reader.next(key,value))
{
       System.out.println("Key is: "+textKey +" value is: "+val+"\n");
}
```

should be replaced with

```
while(reader.next(key,value))
{
       System.out.println("Key is: "+key +" value is: "+value+"\n");
}
```

Use [SequenceFile.Reader#getValueClassName](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.Reader.html#getValueClassName%28%29) to get the value type in the SequenceFile. SequenceFile have the key/value types in the file header.

Comment: Thanks man,the value class is "TypedBytesWritable" can i get the map object from this class?

Comment: [TypedBytesWritable#getValue](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/typedbytes/TypedBytesWritable.html#getValue%28%29) should get the Object.