# Hadoop seq directory with index, data and bloom files -- how to read?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

New to Hadoop...I have a series of HDFS directories with the naming convention filename.seq. Each directory contains an index, data and bloom file. These have binary content and appear to be SequenceFiles (SEQ starts the header). I want to know the structure/schema. Everything I read refers to reading an individual sequence file so I'm not sure how to read these or how they were produced. Thanks.

Update: I've tried recommended tools for streaming & outputting text on the files, none worked:

```
hadoop fs -text /path/to/hdfs-filename.seq/data | head

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2.jar \
-input /path/to/hdfs-filename.seq/data \
-output /tmp/outputfile \
-mapper "/bin/cat" \
-reducer "/bin/wc -l" \
-inputformat SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat
```

Error was:

```
ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: NA
```

Comment: Have you tried reading each of the sequence file individually ? What happens if you do so ?

Comment: I'm also looking for info on how these files are generally produced. According to Hadoop: The Definitive Guide they're Mapfiles (index, data) and definitely SequenceFiles, but the parent dir should be dirname.map, not .seq, In the given example, this should work: hadoop fs -text numbers.map/index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SEQ header confirms that hadoop sequence file. (One thing that I have never seem is the bloom file that you mentioned.)

The structure / schema of a typical Sequence file is:

- Header (version, key class, value class, compression, compression code, metadata)
- Record
- Record length
- Key length
- Key Value
- A sync-marker every few 100 bytes or so.

For more details:

1. see the description [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html).
2. [Sequence file reader](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.Reader.html) and [How to read hadoop sequential file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265256/how-to-read-hadoop-sequential-file)